# How to get rid of files with names bin$

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, code-generation, jooq

Using Jooq generator, by Gradle plugin,  I am getting now with POJOs and tables not only classes with normal names, bu also heaps of files whose names start by bin$.

They are not necessary, for only yesterday the generator did not make these files. And everything works OK with or without them. But I don't want the project to be littered with tens of excessive files.

Comment: [Read about the recycle bin](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#ADMIN11679), which is where these dropped objects are sitting.

Comment: @AlexPoole  thank you, but I  have already found that answer and another one, and had put them here for others.

Comment: Ha, hadn't noticed you'd self-answered, sorry. Might be useful to link to that doc in your answer?

Comment: Huh, interesting. Some `BIN$` objects (namely constraints) are already excluded from code generation, but that should probably be extended to all object types. New feature request for jOOQ 3.10 here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5866. Thanks for bringing this to attention!

Comment: @LukasEder BTW, I couldn't make the "excludes='Bin$*'" command work.

Comment: @LukasEder   And thank YOU for so fast reaction.

Comment: @LukasEder No need. I have single ' there. Groovy does not parse variables in such strings but takes them as is.

Comment: @Gangnus: Well... jOOQ will still parse the string as a regular expression. See [`Pattern.compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-) for details. A `$` has special semantics in regular expressions, and so does an asterisk `*`

Comment: @LukasEder Oh!, yes, sorry. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: @Gangnus: You stil put the asterisk after the dollar. `$*` means any number of repetitions of `$` (end of line). What you really intend to do is `BIN\$.*`, I suspect (where the dot stands for any character)

Comment: @LukasEder :-( No, they are as: BIN$frKctA83wMPgQEOSh0Az+A==$0. So, I really need the star after the dollar.... And in your manual examples * means any continuation. How can I make the plugin to interpret the line this way? Please?

Comment: @LukasEder if it is a regex, then BIN\$.* is the only correct variant. But it doesn't work, either.

Comment: Does `(?i:BIN.*)` work at all? (`(?i:...)` means case-insensitive) and then, leaving out the dollar just to see if that's the issue... Also, what specific example has a single asterisk? Will fix immediately if there's an example/manual bug

Comment: @LukasEder this (?i:BIN.*)  really works. But it is not a real solution, for it ignores also normal tables, starting by 'bin'.

Comment: @Gangnus: OK, just to be sure: The correct regex is `(?i:BIN\$.*)`. But since you put that in a Gradle/Groovy string, Groovy may interpret the backslash prior to passing it to jOOQ, which might mean that it disappears. How about `excludes = '(?i:BIN\\$.*)'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jOOQ's `<excludes/>` setting is a Java regular expression. You have to properly form it like this:

```
excludes = '(?i:BIN\\$.*)'
```

Explanation:

- Use `(?i:...)` for case-insensitivity. Just in case. Pun intended.
- Use `\\` before the `$` sign because the `$` means "end of line" in regular expressions. You want to escape that. And because Groovy/Gradle parses (as in "look for escape sequences") your string, [you need to escape the backslash too](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters), for it to reach the Java [`Pattern.compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-) call
- Use `.*` to indicate that after the `$`, you want to match any number of characters. `.` = any character and `*` = any number of repetitions

Comment: Excellent! The line really works. But the second point of explanation is wrong. For Groovy DOES NOT parse strings in singular quotes '.

Comment: @Gangnus: [Are you sure? :)](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters)

Comment: Absolutely. In http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_quoted_string compare 4.1 against 4.4.  Your reference to 4.3 belongs to triple-quoted strings. I had to bet with you on something :-)

Comment: Might be my glasses, but I only see one apostrophe delimiting the strings in the examples of 4.3.1, not three. Anyway, it works now, right? (With the escaped backslash)

Comment: OK, I see what the confusion is here. When you say "parse", you mean "interpolate". I just mean "look for escape sequences"

Comment: In the same source is written that the only symbol that is escaped in the single-quoted string, is the single quote... And notice, if the escaping worked consistently, you surely wouldn't need half a day to find the correctly working string. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since 10'th version, Oracle puts the dropped tables to the recycle bin. They have names starting by Bin$. So, JooQ simply makes classes for dropped tables. That could be blocked in two ways: To stop use recycling bean in Oracle or to filter the tables for which the Jooq generator makes classes.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET RECYCLEBIN = OFF DEFERRED;
purge dba_recyclebin;
```

or to change the generator setting (the example is for Gradle)

```
generator{
   ...
   database {
      ...
      excludes = '(?i:BIN\\$.*)'
```

Edit: Finally after several attempts (by Lukas) and checks (by me) Lukas had found the correct meaning for `excludes`. Its form, IMHO, has the only explanation - JOOQ doesn't work with regex'es correctly, for Groovy [***does not parse***](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_single_quoted_string) the strings in single quotes.